# How show panel on macOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, panel, iterm

I want to ask how I can do something like this:
[pure](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure)

I mean, I want to show panel and have only icon and name of app.

I'm using iTerm

Comment: What kind of program are you writing, and what are you trying to do? Just linking to that project doesn't make that clear.

Comment: I want to hide panel and still show control icons in iTerm

Comment: What "panel" are you referring to?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/yszZg

I want same transparent panel as have pure theme.

Comment: If you read the readme, you'll find that they use the [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) terminal.

Comment: I know but I want it to iTerm :) or other app. Must be same way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it sounds as though you're asking how to turn the title bar of the window black.

You can't do that. That isn't something that applications running in the terminal have control over.

The screenshot you're referring to is of an application running in [Hyper](https://hyper.is/). Hyper always looks that way; it has nothing to do with the application.